# Python code to count vowels

Tags: python, loops

Assume `s` is a string of lower case characters.

Write a program that counts up the number of vowels contained in the string `s`. Valid vowels are: `'a'`, `'e'`, `'i'`, `'o'`, and `'u'`. For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, your program should print:

Number of vowels: `5`

I have this so far

```
count = 0
vowels = 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'
    for vowels in s:
        count +=1
print ('Number of vowels: ' + count)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: format your code, please.

Comment: I think you need read python documentation about `for` loop first.

Comment: what the heck is `s`?)

Answer (score 10):

A couple of problems. First, your assignment to `vowels` doesn't do what you think it does:

```
>>> vowels = 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'
>>> vowels
'a'
```

Python evaluates `or` lazily; as soon as any of the predicates evaluates `True` it is returned. Non-empty sequences, including strings other than `""` evaluate `True`, so `'a'` is returned straight away.

Second, when you iterate over `s`, you ignore that assignment anyway:

```
>>> for vowels in "foo":
    print(vowels)


f
o
o
```

`for x in y:` assigns each item in the iterable `y` to the name `x` in turn, so anything previously assigned to `x` is not longer accessible via that name.

I think what you want is:

```
count = 0
vowels = set("aeiou")
for letter in s:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to describe what's wrong with current implementation

Answer (score 9):

As a start, try this:

```
In [9]: V = ['a','e','i','o','u']

In [10]: s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

In [11]: sum([1 for i in s if i in V])
Out[11]: 5
```

Comment: Why not have `V` be a string? `'aeiou'`?

Answer (score 7):

Using your own loop.

```
count = 0
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
for char in s:
    if char in vowels: # check if each char in your string is in your list of vowels
        count += 1
print ('Number of vowels: ' + str(count)) # count is an integer so you need to cast it as a str
```

You can use string formatting also:

```
print ('Number of vowels: {} '.format(count))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = len(s)        
a = 0        
c = 0        
while (a < x):        
    if s[a] == 'a' or s[a] == 'e' or s[a] == 'i' or s[a] == 'o' or s[a] == 'u':        
        c += 1        
    a = a+1        
print "Number of vowels: " + str(c)
```

The above code is for beginners

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple one:

```
count = 0    #initialize the count variable

def count_vowel(word):    #define a function for counting the vowels
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'    #A string containing all the vowels
    for i in range(word):    #traverse the string
        if i in vowels:    #check if the the character is contained in the vowel string
            count = count + 1    #update the count
return count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Using while loop:- 
%%time
s = 'services'
m = list(s)
count = 0
while m:
    d = m.pop()
    if (d is 'a') or (d is 'e') or (d is 'i') or (d is 'o') or (d is 'u'):
        count += 1
```

Result is :-
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 18.8 µs
// using for loop one line:-

```
%%time
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
sum([s.count(elem) for elem in vowels])
```

Result is :-
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 18.6 µs

Answer (score 0):

This is also another solution,

```
In [12]: vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

In [13]: str = "azcbobobegghakl"

In [14]: sum([str.count(elem) for elem in vowels])
Out[14]: 5
```

Using `string.count()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that uses Counter and is more compact and even a little faster than Sundar's for larger strings:

```
from collections import Counter 
cnt = Counter('this and that')
sum([cnt[x] for x in 'aeiou'])
```

Here is a time test to compare 3 approaches:

```
import time
from collections import Counter 
s = 'That that is is is not that that is not is not.  This is the understanding of all who begin to think.'
c = Counter(s)
dt1 = dt2 = dt3 = dt4 = 0; 
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
for i in range(100000):
    ms0 = time.time()*1000.0
    s1 = sum([c[x] for x in 'aeiou'])
    ms1 = time.time()*1000.0
    dt1 += ms1 - ms0
for i in range(100000):
    ms1 = time.time()*1000.0
    s2 = sum([c[x] for x in set(vowels).intersection(c.keys())])
    ms2 = time.time()*1000.0
    dt2 += ms2 - ms1
for i in range(100000):
    ms2 = time.time()*1000.0
    s3 = 0
    for char in s:
        if char in vowels: # check if each char in your string is in your list of vowels
            s3 += 1
    ms3 = time.time()*1000.0
    dt3 += ms3 - ms2
print('sums:', s1, s2, s3)
print('times:', dt1, dt2, dt3)
print('relative:  {:.0%}{:.0%}{:.0%}'.format(dt1/dt2, dt2/dt2, dt3/dt2))
```

Results (average of six runs), versions: this, Sundar, simple
    sums: 26 26 26
    times: 392 494 2626
    relative: 80% 100% 532%

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
s = 'aassfgia'
vowels = 0
for x in s:
    if x == 'a' or x == 'e' or x == 'i' or x == 'o' or x == 'u':
        vowels += 1
        print x
print vowels
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting vowels from string

```
s = "Some string here"
```

or

```
s = intput(raw_input("Enter ur string"))

s1 = s.lower()
count = 0
vowels = set("aeiou")
for letter in s1:
  if letter in vowels:
    count += 1
print 'Number of vowels:' ,count
```

this will give u output for total count of vowels in given string

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
for c in s:
    if c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'o' or c == 'u':
        total += 1
print "Number of vowels: " + str(total)
```

ALTERNATE SOLUTION

```
num = 0
for letter in s:
  if letter in "aeiou":
    num+=1
print "Number of vowels:" + str(num)
```

Comment: I get syntax errors on both solutions using both python 2 and 3. (I assume the code is supposed to be v2 due to the print syntax.)  I think it's just a formatting issue, adding linebreaks where appropriate seems to fix it.  I'll edit and format it for clarity.

Comment: On opening the editor it was obvious the code had been entered correctly, but the parser/formatter was compressing the linebreaks.  I added a preformatted block so it appears as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
for letter in s:

    if(letter=='a' or letter == 'e' or letter =='i' or letter =='o' or letter=='u'):
         count=count+1

print("Number of vowels:",count)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you describe what makes this answer useful given that 11 answers already exist? For instance, the answer of @Padraic Cunningham is very close to yours, except than some valuable comments are added. You can hit the "newest" button to answer recent  questions and help askers facing open issues!

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = raw_input('Enter a string: ')

vowels = 0

for char in strings:
    if(char ==('a') or char ==('e') or char ==('i') or char ==('o') or char ==('u')):
        vowels += 1

print('Number of vowels: ' + str(vowels))
```

Comment: Welcomr to Stackoverflow!  It is best in answers to give some explanation as to why your answer is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array. That is a sequence of element, in your case characters. Here is a way to define an array in Python:

```
vowels  = ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution making use of an `in` operator and a `for` loop:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

count = 0
for i in s.lower():
    if i in "aeiou":
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Why `s.lower()`? To make it work with any string containing vowels in capitals.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'aeioubbaeiouggaeiouss'
vow = set("aeiouAEIOU")
count = 0

for alpha in str:
    if alpha in vow:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Count will give total number of times vowels came in string.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        num_vowels += 1
print (num_vowels)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

***you can you this code to find count***

```
  mystr='hello world'
    
  count= sum(1 if c.lower() in 'aeiou' else 0 for c in mystr) 

   #output:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputstring =input("Enter a string")
vowels = "aeiuoAEIOU"
print(len([letter for letter in inputstring if letter in vowels]))
print([letter for letter in inputstring if letter in vowels])
```

This should allow to get the count and show the vowels in a string inputted or supplied

Answer (score -1):

A different implementation using counter

```
from collections import Counter
s='azcbobobegghakl'
vowels="aeiou"
c=Counter(s)
print sum([c[i] for i in set(vowels).intersection(c.keys())])
```

the statement `set(vowels).intersection(c.keys())` this returns the dictint vowels present in the sentence

Comment: You don't need `c.keys()`, just `c` - dictionaries' keys are iterated over by default. Also, you could simplify your `sum` with `c.get(i, 0)`.

Answer (score -1):

`print("\nThe count of vowels are:",sum([1 for i in input("\nEnter the string\n\n").lower() if i in ['a','e','i','o','u']]),"\n")`

Enter the string

azcbobobegghakl

The count of vowels are: 5

`print("\nThe count of vowels are:",sum([1 for i in input("\nEnter the string\n\n").lower() if i in ['a','e','i','o','u']]),"\n")`

Enter the string

azCBOBOBegghakl

The count of vowels are: 5